# Supporting custom URL protocol on Mac/Linux

Tags: cross-platform, browser-addons

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) discusses how to register an application for a custom protocol on Windows but [how] can the same be achieved on Mac & Linux? And is this always an OS-level task or does it have to be registered per-browser?